# Is there a relation or formula between the correlations of the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function and the correlations between high points

Tags: pr.probability, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Consider an interval of length $(\log T)^{\theta}$ for some fixed $\theta > −1$, around a point $1/2 + i y$ on the critical line where $y\in[T,2T]$ and $T$ is large. How do the correlations between the points $t$ for which $\log|\zeta|(1/2 + i (t + y))$ is above a given threshold compare with the correlations between the nontrivial zeros on the same interval ?

Basically, my question boils down to this: Is there a way to reformulate the Montgomery pair correlation conjecture in terms of high points of $\log|\zeta|$ instead of the zeros of zeta ?

Comment: Have you looked at the paper "Mesoscopic fluctuation of the Zeta zeros" by Bourgade?
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.1757.pdf

Comment: Yes, I did look.